# 'mkdir .dist' keeps randomly appearing in bash history

Tags: bash, terminal, command-history

Short question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. Why is `mkdir .dist` randomly appearing in my Bash history all of a sudden? I haven't been typing it and it's a bit annoying to scroll past when trying to find previous commands. I'm on Pop_OS! if that helps.

Edit: it seems to "inject" the command into history.

e.g. 7PM I can scroll up and see my commands `python test.py`, etc.

Then at say 8pm I'll see: `python test.py`, `mkdir .dist`, etc.

Could a program cause this or is this an OS thing?

Comment: you could set up incrontab IN_OPEN for lsof to trace whats going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone or something is connecting to your account and executing a bash shell with that command.

Add something like this to you bash profile (after taking a backup of it):

```
(date; who -a; ps -ef) >> /tmp/bash_logon.txt
```

Do NOT log out when you've done that, try a new logon first to see if you still can.   Remove that line when you've seen enough.

Comment: how should I go about troubleshooting where its coming from though and what would constantly making .dist do?

Comment: I forgot to add this, but it seems to 'inject' it after the fact into the history. I've scrolled up once, and it wasn't there, but say an hour later, it suddenly appears there.

Comment: I would add some logging to my bash profile, store the results of a "who", "ps -ef" and "date".  Check that log an hour later.

Comment: Thank you. Could you point me in the right direction to doing this? I know how to add things to a bash profile but I don't know how to add a logger. Also, would this log things even when I have the terminal window closed?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: So, who was the culprit?

Comment: No clue... I tried your and alecxs' ideas and I could never trace it (almost definitely because I'm newish to linux). I ended up saving important files and reinstalling the os.

Comment: Are you using github?

Comment: Using github for what?

Comment: Brushing your teeth maybe?  It's just that "dist" folders are uset by github, so perhaps you had a job running to synchronize your directories with a github server.  The problem doesn't reproduce itself with the new installation?

Comment: Ahh no. I wasn't using github for anything like that. So far it hasn't reproduced itself so it was probably something I downloaded. I have downloaded stuff from github so maybe some program caused it.